# Error when granting privilege - Mysql GRANT is deprecated, use ALTER USER instead

Tags: mysql

I'm using the latest version of mysql. When running the below command, its asking me to use the ALTER USER command instead of GRANT. I don't see the syntax to use the ALTER USER command to update privileges anywhere. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by ‘1234’;
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation of [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) mentions:

> **Note**
>
> If an account named in a `GRANT` statement does not already exist, `GRANT` may create it under the conditions described later in the discussion of the `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER SQL` mode. It is also possible to use `GRANT` to specify nonprivilege account characteristics such as whether it uses secure connections and limits on access to server resources.
>
> However, use of `GRANT` to create accounts or define nonprivilege characteristics is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.6. Instead, perform these tasks using `CREATE USER` or `ALTER USER`.

The `IDENTIFIED by ‘1234’` part of your query is used to set/change the password of the user.  The password is not a privilege, it should be changed using `ALTER USER`.

Use:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

to grant the desired privileges to the user and:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234'
```

to change its password, if needed.

#### Remark

It is worth mentioning that the [`ALTER USER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-user.html) statement was [introduced in MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-additions). For older versions, the `GRANT` statement is the only way to change the user's password.

Comment: Nice answer. I deleted my incorrect answer. Still want to mention though that as far as I know the root-user should not be used.

Comment: GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'%'; to avoid issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036547/mysql-grant-read-only-options/20061002