# Safely reading RDS instance database in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am newly working with AWS as a service for a wordpress website
I am not familiar with how to safely view the SQL data and do not wish to crash/modify/edit any of the data but simply to read it

From the RDS > Instances > Name I dont see anything that screams read only safe inspection sort of deal, any clarification on safely looking into the data would be great

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to create a read-only user in the database. For example, if you're using MySQL, you could do it [as described in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20061002/9647776). Then in your application, you would use the username and password of the read-only user to access data in the database.

If you prefer using IAM to authenticate instead of the database username/password (you get things like automatic password rotation etc. for free), you can set up a read-only database user and then connect it to an IAM user as described in [this AWS knowledge center post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/).