# Allow a DB User to access a single Database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm new to google cloud.

I created a Google Cloud SQL Instance.
Added multiple DBs and few users.

How can I restrict an user to single database ?
and
How can I restrict an user to single database with ReadOnly permission ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720244/create-new-user-in-mysql-and-give-it-full-access-to-one-database) post in regards to restricting access to only one database for a user; and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036547/mysql-grant-read-only-options) you can find more information related to "Read Only" access using MySQL.

Comment: thank you :) are you aware of any google cloud SQL alternative..   where i can create db, users. and assign users to DB with some UI..  :) .   any alternatives..:)

Comment: Google Cloud SQL provides you with all of that. What do you think could be improved to better fit your needs?