# Is it safe to add a linux user to the `mysql` group?

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions, user-permissions

I want one of my Linux users to be able to see the size of table files in `/var/lib/mysql/[db]/...`, but these dirs are owned by `mysql:mysql` and everyone does not have read access. Is it safe to add a normal user to the `mysql` group?

Answer (score 1):

All things about security that I learned is about give access **Only** if it's **absolutely necessary**. Said that, you can think convenient to give them only read permissions, and for that, create new roles:
[MySQL - How to grant read only permissions to a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036547/mysql-grant-read-only-options)

And if the users need to read the file (only the system file), you'll be opening the archives for their by making a specific group with the right permissions. And yes, is convenient, less secure, but resolve your problem.